# Postgres Regex not working as expected

Tags: php, sql, regex, postgresql

I have a query which loads a lot of fields, and removes duplicate spaces, tabs and line breaks.

```
regexp_replace(FIELD, E'[\|\\s\\n\\r]+', ' ', 'g' ) as FIELD
```

When I test this using Sql Manager for PostgreSQL (Windows Environment), it works as expected. But...

But this query is at a PHP file, which is ran daily using crontab (Linux Environment), it remove duplicate spaces, tabs, line breaks **and "s"**

Example, the string ahead:

```
"Small 

unicorns are   smart"
```

Turns into:

```
"mall unicorn are mart"
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: You probably need to double escape those \'s, or remove the double escaping, without the actual code it is hard to tell. What do you see if you just `echo` your query?

Comment: And also `\r` and `\n` are subgroup of `\s` (whitespace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to double escape the `\` in php (unlike, say, Java). You're actually escaping the backslash, turning the special characters into literal letters. Or, if I'm totally wrong, you actually need a double escape.

Try:

```
[\|\s\n\r]+
```

Also, as Maxim points out, \r and \n are already included in \s.

**Edit:**

looks like you're trying to include a literal pipe in there too. In that case, use `[|\s]+` http://regex101.com/r/nE3dI8

If you need it double escaped, `[|\\\s]+`

Comment: But "\" has a meaning inside a `E''` string in PostgreSQL so you need to double them to get a single "\" down to the PostgreSQL regex engine. Then you probably have to escape each of those to get them past PHP.

Comment: @muistooshort blast, you're probably right. So probably needs to be double escaped `[|\\\s]+`

Comment: Best bet is to experiment on sqlfiddle.com to get the right number of escaped escapes and then double them to get them through PHP. What a mess.

Comment: @muistooshort I think perhaps `\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ ` :P

Comment: Best to embed the PHP inside a shell script inside a C program first, then keep adding more backslashes until your keyboard breaks.

Comment: @muistooshort can I wrap it in Haskell generated by COBOL too?

Comment: @remus, I needed to double escape, exactly as you stated in last line. Thanks!